# Перестановка в массиве php

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив, всего 12 элементов

```
$sources    = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
```

Мне нужно переставить элементы как показано далее,

```
$collection = [
            $sources[0],
            $sources[3],
            $sources[6],
            $sources[9],
            $sources[1],
            $sources[4],
            $sources[7],
            $sources[10],
            $sources[2],
            $sources[5],
            $sources[8],
            $sources[11],
        ];
```

Какие могут быть варианты? Без такого велосипеда

Comment: Ваш велосипед на самом деле это самый эффективный и понятный способ. Как вариант по наглядности еще будет добавить массив нового порядка ключей

Comment: @teran Я столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия элементов в массиве, и этот изначально простой способ превратился в
if (isset($sources[0])) { $collection[] = $sources[0] } Что конечно нельзя назвать элегантным решением

Answer (score 4):

```
$sources    = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
$dest = array_map(function($i) use ($sources){
    return $sources[3*($i%4)+intval($i/4)];
}, array_keys($sources));

echo json_encode($dest);
// [0,3,6,9,1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11]
```

Или, что то же самое

```
$sources    = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
$dest = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($sources); $i++) {
  $dest[] = $sources[3*($i%4)+intval($i/4)];
}

echo json_encode($dest);
// [0,3,6,9,1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11]
```

---

Масштабируемый вариант:

```
$sources    = [
    0,1,2,3,4,5,
    6,7,8,9,'A','B'
];
$n = count($sources);
$sliceTo = 2;
$dest = array_map(function($i) use ($sources, $n, $sliceTo){
    return $sources[($n/$sliceTo)*($i%$sliceTo)+($i/$sliceTo)];
}, array_keys($sources));

echo json_encode($dest);
// [0,6,1,7,2,8,3,9,4,"A",5,"B"]
```

Comment: блин, не успел опубликовать :D

Comment: еще можно адский вариант с array_chunk, array_map и array_merge написать :)

Comment: Да ну его нафиг) Действительно адский)

Comment: uksort самый простой будет вариант,если индексы считать. А если не считать то chunk, column и merge

Comment: Плохо, когда самый простой вариант за O(nlogn) при наличии варианта за O(n). Не нужна тут сортировка.

Comment: что-то с uksort я погорячился  :) спать надо в такое время :D

Answer (score 3):

альтернативный вариант, для уже опубликованного ответа, для тех кто не знаком с функциями обработки массивов.

```
$sources    = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

$result = [];
$idx = 0;
foreach($sources as $k => $v){
    $idx = $k / 3  + $k % 3 * 4;
    $result[$idx] = $v;
}

ksort($result);
```

---

На месте автора для подобной разовой фиксированной перестановки элементов я бы завел простой массив новых индексов, и использовал бы его. Это, пожалуй, самый простой и наглядный способ.

```
$order = [0,3,6,9,1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11];
$result = [];
foreach($order as $oldIdx => $newIdx){
     $result[$newIdx] = $sources[$newIdx];
}
```

При чем этому циклу есть альтернатива в виде функции [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php):

```
$sources  = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
$order    = [0,3,6,9,1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11];
$result   = array_combine($order, $sources);
```

---

еще одна из вариаций для фиксированного числа элементов без расчета соответствия старых и новых индексов:

```
$x = array_chunk($sources, 3);
$result = array_merge(
              array_column($x,0),
              array_column($x,1),
              array_column($x,2)
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

Тестируем варианты с `array_combine()`:

```
$sources  = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
$order    = [0,3,6,9,1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11];
$result   = array_combine($order, $sources);
var_dump($result);
$result   = array_combine($sources, $order);
ksort($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Результаты:

```
C:\wamp64\www\2017\17_04_06_combine_chunk\index.php:5:
array (size=12)
  0 => int 0
  3 => int 1
  6 => int 2
  9 => int 3
  1 => int 4
  4 => int 5
  7 => int 6
  10 => int 7
  2 => int 8
  5 => int 9
  8 => int 10
  11 => int 11
C:\wamp64\www\2017\17_04_06_combine_chunk\index.php:8:
array (size=12)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 3
  2 => int 6
  3 => int 9
  4 => int 1
  5 => int 4
  6 => int 7
  7 => int 10
  8 => int 2
  9 => int 5
  10 => int 8
  11 => int 11
```

Вывод:

Идея красивая, но не всё так просто.